# Latex font for replacing 'Verdana' of MS Word

Tags: fonts, pdftex, msword

My professor wants me to document my Thesis in Word with 'Verdana' font. I would prefer to submit a pdf file with the same font using Latex. Which font would be the best to use in LaTex?

Comment: In XeTeX/LuaTeX, you can actually use Verdana. Otherwise, DejaVu font family would be a nice alternative (they have both text and math fonts).

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question:
The font is a matter of taste, but you can check https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/fonts/verdana.

Comment: Try using `\sffamily` before `\begin{document}`. It's not Verdana but somewhat similar...

Comment: Also, I don't think you're a noob.

Comment: If your professor expects you to write in Word and you then hand in a PDF not from Word, wouldn't that be problematic? (I'm all for the choice of the student to use what ever tool they want, some advisors expect to be able to edit their students thesis using Word)

Comment: I am using a pdf-latex template. '\usepackage{helvet}' is written in it. If I replace it with '\usepackage{Verdana}', the output font is quite different from what I would get in a Word File.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows or MacOS X, you already have Verdana installed. If you are using Linux, install the Microsoft Core Fonts (eg https://www.ostechnix.com/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/ for Ubuntu). In your thesis, delete any `\usepackage` commands for `inputenc` or `fontenc`, and add `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead, plus `\setsansfont{Verdana}`. Then you will be able to use `\sffamily` and `\textsf{…}` to get Verdana.

Comment: But I think your prof doesn't understand much about fonts — what about mathematics? JairoAraujo's suggestion about DejaVu is good.

Comment: as I said, I am using pdf-latex, and 'inputenc' is not an applicable syntax according to MikTex

Comment: inputenc and fontenc are packages, so I am referring to lines like \usepackage{inputenc} or \usepackage{fontenc}. I don't understand what you were trying to do that would have elicited a complaint from MiKTeX about syntax.