# How to use Verdana without Serifs in pdfLatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, sans-serif

I used the following code to finally get Verdana font in pdf-Latex. But it has Serifs. How do I make it 'Sans Serifs' ?

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
begin{document}
\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont
```

Comment: well if this doesn't give a sans serif font it is not verdana but probably cmr. Check the log-file it should tell you that verdana wasn't found.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, please put your fragments into a compilable document that people can play with.If you look at the log file/console output, you're getting Computer Modern. There is no `verdana` font like this. The log says: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape` `T1/verdana/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using` `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.`.

Comment: The simplest way to use Verdana is to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `fontspec` and use the system version of the font.  See [Verdana and Cambria Font](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/452917)

Comment: In your earlier question it was suggested to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537662/35864. Is there any reason why you insist on pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @moewe. I have atemplate for the Thesis and I want to use this to save time.

Comment: Often it is quite possible to switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX with not too much hassle, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/35864. (Often it also turns out that bad templates cost more time than they save ...)

Comment: don't ignore warnings, the warnings clearly tell you here that the font switch has not worked and so you have the default computer modern font

Answer (score 3):

The verdana support for pdflatex (in the winfonts package) is broken (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339269/2388). So if you want to use verdana, use xelatex or lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\begin{document}
Verdana
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way to use Verdana (or in fact an equally looking replacement) without serifs in latex.

```
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```